# Двойной род - это норма?

Tags: род

К примеру, возьмём слово "матриарх". Это слово мужского рода, но означает женщину. Как согласовываются с ним прилагательные и глаголы прошлого времени? Мне кажется, в текстах любят использовать с такими словами глаголы в женском роде и прилагательные в мужском, типа:

- "Госпожа президент заявила"
- "благодаря посланию покойного матриарха"

А если нужно одновременно и глагол, и прилагательное, тогда как? "Новоизбранный президент поблагодарила"?

Comment: I would avoid this awkward situation by changing the whole phrase. "Новоизбранная глава государства поблагодарила".

Comment: @il--ya I disagree. "Новоизбранный президент поблагодарила" is a right phrase and sounds better that what you are proposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий ответ:
Наиболее употребительно: **будущий** врач **сказала**.
(с) gramota.ru

Длинный ответ здесь:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89

Появился **новый** автор Петрова. (Необособленное определение - в мужском роде.)
Автор Петрова, уже **известная** читателям, предложила новую статью. (Обособленное определение стоит после имени.)

Увлекательные заметки **предложил** редакции известный автор Н. Петрова.
Автор Н. Петрова **предложила** редакции увлекательные заметки. (Глагол после имени автора.)

Comment: Как быть с матриархом? М. попросил или М. попросила?

Comment: Я бы предложила по аналогии с примерами с gramota.ru:  
**Появился** новый матриарх.   
Новый матриарх **сказала**.   
   
Но мне кажется более натуральным сказать один раз, к примеру, "Руководила всеми Мария - матриах." И дальше называть ее по имени, а не каждый раз матриархом. Или какой-то ещё синоним использовать, с которым не надо так мучаться.

Comment: A если матриарха зовут Копье Решимости?

Comment: :) Копьё, мне кажется, вообще ничего не изменит. "Матриарх Копьё" будет так же себя вести, как просто "матриарх".  
  
Вы еще подумайте про варианты типа: роман "Отцы и дети", сеть ресторанов "Рожки да Ножки". :)

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание с прилагательными звучит ужасно в такой ситуации, на мой вкус. Хоть в мужском роде, хоть в женском. "Меня осматривала молодая врач", "меня осматривала молодой врач"... Остаётся только перефразировать на что-нибудь типа "меня осматривала врач, молодая девушка".

(кажется, я стал сторонником феминитивов)

Comment: There's a word `врачиха` but I would be careful using it.

Comment: Для первого упоминания годится, а если в тексте "врач-женщина" повторяется 10+ раз?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko использовать имя-отчество.

Answer (score 1):

Похожие сложности возникают и в фентезийной литературе, где непонятно как писать о женских представителях таких рас как тролли, эльфы, гоблины, гномы (все эти слова мужского рода, а соответствующие феминитивы имеют сильный оттенок пренебрежения). Там эта проблема решается стилистическими приёмами: подбором синонимического ряда, состоящего из слов нужного рода.

Для вашего случая тоже можно подобрать синоним женского рода и пользоваться им: "**глава государства**". Ну или можно изредка вставлять "госпожа", как в обращениях: "Госпожа президент поблагодарила избирателей".